# Parsing nested json with python

Tags: python, json

After submitting a request I have received the following json back:

```
{"type": [
{"ID": "all", "count": 1, "references": [
    { "id": "Boston,MA,02118", "text": "Boston,MA,02118", "val": "Boston,MA,02118", "type": 1 ,"zip": "02118","city": "Boston","state": "MA","lt": "42.3369","lg": "-71.0637","s": ""}
] }
] }
```

I captured the response in variable j ,

```
>>> j
'{"type": [\r\n\t{"ID": "all", "count": 1, "references": [\r\n\t\t{ "id": "Boston,MA,02118", "text": "Boston,MA,02118", "val": "Boston,MA,02118", "type": 1 ,"zip": "02118","city": "Boston","state": "MA","lt": "42.3369","lng": "-71.0637","s": ""}\r\n\t] }\r\n] }'
```

and am trying to parse it:

```
>>> j['types']
TypeError: string indices must be integers, not str
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You've got a JSON string representation of a dictionary. But you're trying to use that string as a dictionary. That won't work; you need to parse it first, using the [`json`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html) module:

```
import json
obj = json.loads(j)
obj['types']
```

(There are libraries that can wrap up the whole "send a request, get a response, pull the body out of the response, make sure the content-type is right for JSON, parse it, raise an exception if anything goes wrong" for you. But if you're not using one, you can't skip any of the steps.)

Comment: I think he also misspell the key `type`

Comment: @FlilyHsuL Yeah, I think you're right. But at least he'll get a `KeyError` instead of a `TypeError`, and hopefully that'll be easier to understand. (Or, hopefully, he'll read your comment…)

Comment: Thank you, but that was just a typo - Bill